# Ubuntu 14.04 Host Win XP Pro Corp SP3 Guest How to Share HP AIO Printer

Tags: networking, drivers, virtualbox, printing, hp

I have a Dell XPS L702X Laptop 64-Bit running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for host OS. VirtualBox Guest is Win XP Pro Corp SP3. I have an HP ENVY 5530 DeskJet printer USB attached to laptop for host. I am trying to share it to the guest in order to use all of its AIO features, especially scanning. Everything works fine when using the host (Ubuntu). When I go to the guest (Win XP) the best I have been able to do is print a test page after an error that Windows cannot communicate with the printer (seems like a time delay problem). I have been able to satisfactorily print with it, even with the time delay problem. The printer is set up with CUPS in Ubuntu for sharing. No errors. I can go to the browser in the guest and enter the IP address to find the printer (10.0.0.5:631/printers/ENVY_5530_series) and the CUPS admin page displays. However, if I try to scan with this AIO I keep getting the message that Windows cannot communicate with the printer. When I use the Windows Printer Wizard to add the printer, tell it the printer is attached to another computer in our work-group and enter the same IP address info above (10.0.0.5:631/printers/ENVY_5530_series) that the browser was able to find, I immediately get the error that Windows cannot communicate with the printer. Does anyone have any suggestions to point me in the right direction to resolve this issue. I have spent the better part of 2 days trying everything I have been able to think of, but have had no success. This computer is my wife's, and she has no patience to let me find a solution.